# are there uses for '>&0' (redirect to stdin)?

Tags: bash, unix

In bash you can do:

- `echo test >&1` (redirect to stdout, although it's already going there)
- `echo test >&2` (redirect to stderr)
- `echo test >&0` (redirect to stdin)

When I do the last one my terminal still prints `test` as it would with the other two, but it's hard to know why. So first off, why does this work at all? Secondly, are there any good uses for redirecting to stdin?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To be more precise, what `>&0` does is duplicate file descriptor 0 as file descriptor 1. If the program's stdin is only open for reading, then when your program tries to write to stdout (file descriptor 1), it will get an error because file descriptor 1 is also only open for reading.

You can demonstrate this by writing a small shell script that inspects its own file descriptors:

10156115.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
bash -c 'ls -l /proc/$$/fd' >&0
```

And then invoke it with identifiable stdin, stdout and stderr:

```
$ touch stdin
$ ./10156115.sh < stdin > stdout 2> stderr
```

The result is that you get the following in `stderr`:

```
ls: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

However, by default, all three are a terminal: (output simplified)

```
$ ls -l /proc/$$/fd
lrwx------ 0 -> /dev/pts/14
lrwx------ 1 -> /dev/pts/14
lrwx------ 2 -> /dev/pts/14
lrwx------ 255 -> /dev/pts/14
```

Typically, all three are actually open read+write, so the `>&0` redirect has no effect at all if used alone from a normal shell.

---

Are there any uses for this?

There aren't any common uses of this, but you might use it as a dirty hack to get a way to print to the terminal if whomever calls your script redirects `stdout` and `stderr`, and for whatever reason you're not able to change that:

```
if [ ! -t /dev/fd/1 -a ! -t /dev/fd/2 -a -t /dev/fd/0 ]; then
    echo "My message that I really, really want to go to a terminal" >&0
fi
```

But I wouldn't recommend actually doing this.

Answer (score 7):

For historical reasons, the standard file descriptors on a terminal are open read/write instead of read-only (specifically, it's opened once and `dup()`ed to the others).  This is occasionally useful for programs that want to take piped input but also read input from the user (from `stdout`, or more commonly `stderr`), although using `/dev/tty` is more reliable in that case.  Some systems apply this to more than just ttys:  the *BSDs open socketpairs ("pipes") bidirectionally, and some system utilities (I recall `ufsdump` being an example) depend on this.

Redirecting *to* `stdin` (that is, having it open only for write) is not generally useful, since most programs expect it to be open for read (or sometimes read/write, as above).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a good use for `>&0`. If I want to redirect input and output to the same device (e.g. serial port), I can open stdin in read-write mode and redirect stdout to it:

```
rz <>/dev/ttyUSB0 >&0
```

Not only does it save me some typing, I makes shellcheck happy if I do it in a script.