# Is there a use for redirecting to stdin with `>&0` in windows command line?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, dos, history

I've tried to redirect an output to stdin like in bash `>&0`, as featured in the question [are there uses for '>&0' (redirect to stdin)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10156115/are-there-uses-for-0-redirect-to-stdin).

I've got `The system cannot write to the specified device.`

I've also tried `>&1` out of curiosity which gives

```
The handle could not be duplicated
during redirection of handle 1.
```

To my knowledge there are no multiple terminals on windows and neither were there on DOS.

What is, even if historical, the use of allowing redirection to `0` in Windows?

Comment: It *isn't* allowed.  That's why you got the error message.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I disagree. the message is about an attempt that failed. it is not systematically disallowed. it tries to do it or simulates to attempt to do it, and fails. There is an infrastructure built that allows it. if it weren't allowed, it should say that the attempt is **invalid**, not failed.

Comment: That would require `cmd.exe` to explicitly detect that you're doing something that isn't allowed and stop you.  Why should it bother?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirection itself, `>&0`, doesn't fail nor does it print an error message. It results in the standard output file handle being replaced by a duplicate of the standard input handle. The failure you see happens when something then tries to write to the new standard output handle. Presumably you did something like `echo foo >&0` so it was `echo` that failed and caused the error message, not the redirection.

The reason `echo` fails when it writes to the new standard output handle is because the handle only allows read access. When Windows created the command window it opened `CONIN$`, which is a read-only device, and assigned to standard input. As the new standard output handle refers to this read-only device the `echo` command fails.

Similarly Windows also opens `CONOUT$`, a write-only device and assigns the handle to standard output and error. Notably this behaviour is different than on Unix where the same "tty" device is opened once for read and write access and is duplicated to become the initial shell's standard input, output and error file descriptors. This is why `>&0` generally works on Unix, and generally fails on Windows.

There are basically two possible ways `>&0` can be used without an error. The first is simply for the program that the redirection was applied to not to ever write to it. For example `type nul >&0` doesn't result in an error. So would a program that only read from standard output, though such a program would normally fail.

The other case is where something has previously redirected standard input. In that case standard input wouldn't be `CONIN$` and wouldn't necessarily be read-only. If were opened with read/write access by some other process (cmd only apparently opens files read-only or write-only) then the `>&0` redirection would work as expected.

So there's not a lot of legitimate reasons to use `>&0`, however it's just one of a number of possible handle duplicating redirections involving other pairs of handles. In particular `2>&1` is very useful. Since `>&0` can work in certain circumstances there's no reason to treat it specially and have cmd reject it outright.

Comment: msdn "Console Handles": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682075%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: what about a pipe operator, it writes to the stdin then? Is the stdin of the 2nd command separate to the input buffer of the console?

Comment: @LewisKelsey The pipe operator creates two file handles, one for writing that becomes the left side's standard output, and one for reading that becomes right side's standard input. These two handles are connected through an anonymous pipe object, something written to the first handle can be read using the second handle. Neither handle is a console handle.

Comment: @RossRidge so when you pipe to an executable, I'm guessing the executable starts with that anonymous pipe handle in its process parameter block i.e. cmd.exe uses `CreateProcess` and specifies it in `STARTUPINFO`, and it's up to the executable to read from its stdin